# Using Two Linked Lists

Tags: c++, pointers, error-handling, operator-overloading

I need to create two separate linked lists and then compare them. However, when I try to create a second list with the same operator overloading for the constructor, I get an error:

"A value of type polynomial2* cannot be used to initialize an entity of the type polynomial*"

Here is my code for that sections:

Header:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std; 

struct polynomial
{ 
    polynomial();
    polynomial(string newCoefficient, string newPower, polynomial *nextPtr);
    string coefficient;
    string power;
    polynomial *next; 
};

struct polynomial2
{ 
    polynomial2();
    polynomial2(string newCoefficient2, string newPower2, polynomial2 *nextPtr2);
    string coefficient2;
    string power2;
    polynomial *next2; 
};

class linkedList
{
public:
    linkedList();
    void callFunctions();
private:
    polynomial *head;
    polynomial2 *head2;
    void makeList(polynomial *head, polynomial2 *head2);
    void showList(polynomial *head);
    void compareNodes(polynomial *head, polynomial2 *head2);
};

#endif
/* defined(__Assignment3__Polynomial__) */
```

.CPP Code:

```
linkedList::linkedList()
{
    head = 0; 
};

polynomial::polynomial()
{
    coefficient = " "; 
    power = " "; 
    next = NULL;
};

polynomial2::polynomial2()
{
    coefficient2 = " "; 
    power2 = " "; 
    next2 = NULL
};

polynomial::polynomial(string newCoefficient, string newPower, polynomial *nextPtr )
    :
coefficient(newCoefficient),
    power(newPower), 
    next(nextPtr) 

{}

polynomial2::polynomial2(string newCoefficient2, string newPower2, polynomial2 *nextPtr2)
    :
coefficient2(newCoefficient2),
    power2(newPower2), 
    next2(nextPtr2)

{}
```

The error appears on the last line of the .cpp file at "next2(nextPtr2)". "nextPtr2" is underlined

Comment: Why are you creating two different polynomial types, rather than two instances of a single polynomial type? Other than that comment, I believe @Mash has the answer to your error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your polynomial2 definition, did you mean to put:

```
polynomial2 *next2;
```

instead of

```
polynomial *next2;
```

Comment: Yes it is! Ah, such a minor error caused me so much grief, thank you Mash!

Comment: @AndrewT no problem, it's usually the minor errors that are tough to catch, so having others look at your code helps... but following paddy's suggestion would be a more proper solution to your problem... this is more of a quick fix

Comment: Indeed, I have implemented Paddy's suggestion as well as yours actually! I was reading the guidelines, and it turns out that my professor actually wanted me to store the two linked lists in a completely separate linked list after we add/subtract them! Got the best of both worlds on this one :) Thank you again!

Answer (score 2):

Compile errors aside for a moment, I think you may be barking up the wrong tree.

The key here is that you want to compare two lists that essentially have the same data type.

I have a strong feeling that you don't actually want two separate list datatypes - you only want one.

So you should really get rid of `polynomial2` and do this:

```
polynomial *list1;
polynomial *list2;
```

Comment: This seems to be the root problem. @AndrewT You dont need to define a new type for each instance you intend to have! At first I thought you were defining two almost identical types for some template trick. Did you consider using an existing implementation such as [`std::list`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/)?.

Comment: To be honest, I have only begun to really consider code re-use, and programming in C++ in general! I'm a beginner and old habits die hard apparently! Haha. I did take your comment into consideration, and it does do the job perfectly without the use of all of the extra baggage of the 'polynomial2' code! As such, I've never really used the standard library when coding which is why I haven't given it much thought. Perhaps I'll delve into it more as I get further in my coding career! Thank you very much for your help, I appreciate it. I've learned a lot from you alone Paddy :)

Answer (score 2):

And also, since you're already using stl, what's the reason for not using std::list<>?

```
struct polynomial
{ 
    polynomial()
      :coefficient(" "), power(" ") {}
    polynomial(string newCoefficient, string newPower)
      :coefficient(newCoefficient), power(newPower) {}
    string coefficient;
    string power;
};
```

And then

```
list<polynomial> list1;
```

You can compare the lists for equality, if you have an equality operator on your polynomial. And probably do all the other things you need to do also. Unless the assignment you've been given disallows the use of std::list, which I guess it might.

Comment: Our professor restricted the use of STL's for our assignments since he believe it is better to hard-code the program in order to understand the workings and logic of what he is attempting to teach! I haven't done any practice with the library either which is why I haven't given it any thought. Thank you for your help though, I'll be sure to try your suggestions out as well :)